# It is possible to use node.js library in php

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm

I'm doing a project in laravel and i need to use this library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/lunar-calendar) but this is for node.js.

There is any chance to use this in my laravel project?
I also find this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-require.

What i have to do?

Thank you

Comment: PHP is not JavaScript. So no, you can't run one from the other without doing something like a command line call to call the other file and return the result.

Comment: I don't understand the documentation, but it seems to me that this is a frontend library. You don't need node (backend) to use it, just copy it to you public folder, call it from you views and you're set. npm is just package manager, it's a convenient way to download libraries, but it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot use JS library in PHP, And `npm` is a tool used to download libraries.

What you can do :

Get your [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lunar-calendar).

Copy it to your public folder and call it from the views based on your conditions.